# When to prefer XAMPP over a complete installation of Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, xampp

In which cases, except development, would you prefer XAMPP over a complete installation and configuration of Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than development, the only other time I use it is for demos - it's nice being able to take a "solution on a stick" to a customer.

I'd never consider it for a live/public site though.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that XAMPP would be preferred over a complete manual install, whenever one is not confident enough, skilled enough, experienced enough, or educated enough to properly install, the OS, HTTP server, database server, and language system with all the mainstream security and stability aspects in mind, and compensated for.

Although I recognize that XAMPP is not perfect, it is, in 99% of cases, much better than anyone without proper knowledge could accomplish.

Comment: I think that if someone doesn't understand the stack they are developing for they need to take some time to learn it. If you don't understand how to set up a LAMP stack, how can you diagnose problems with Xampp?

Comment: well you cant but it can provide a working solution that can be useful learning the basic systems and config files.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is great for development because it's simple and fast.

It's not about lack of skill or knowledge to build a server. It's a simpler solution. It's great if you want to use PHP and MySQL. I wouldn't try to run a production server or try to add modules to it.

Answer (score -2):

LAMP will perform 4x better

Benchmarks: http://www.formboss.net/blog/2010/02/hosting-php-linux-vs-windows-benchmarks/

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"Nothing Here!"*